# Is there any software which makes my Data entry as well as error correction jobs easier?

Tags: data, data-entry

Actually, I just need a software solution for my new startup company. Its a data entry company and I just want to convert hand written font characters to Times New Roman italics and so on.

- It must Run on a windows OS.
- We are willing to meet at any price if that suits our requirement.
- Data must be stored in html format

  Is there any software which suits my actual requirement in that.

  Also I just need an error correction software which finds out spelling mistakes in common used words. Can anyone help me in building a solution ?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS should it run on? What is your price margin? Are we talking about OCR here? What format shall the data be stored in?